# Why does CheckUrlAccessForPrincipal still return true when authorization has been revoked on a page level?

Tags: asp.net, authorization

I'm building a dynamic navigation control which toggles the visiblity of elements in the navigation depending on which pages the user is authorized to view in the web.config.

To find out if a user is allowed to visit a page, I use the [CheckUrlAccessForPrincipal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.security.urlauthorizationmodule.checkurlaccessforprincipal?view=netframework-4.7.2) method and set the authorization rules  for a whole directory like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
<system.web>
    <authorization>
        <allow roles="demo\Administrators"/>
        <deny users="*" />
    </authorization>
</system.web>
</configuration>
```

This works just as expected and CheckUrlAccessForPrincipal returns false for all pages in the directory that contains the web.config-file when the current user is not in the Administrators group.

Now I want to set authorization rules on a page level like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
<location path="DemoPage.aspx">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow roles="demo\SomeDifferentGroup"/>
            <deny users="*" />
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
</configuration>
```

If I now check whether a user is allowed to access DemoPage, CheckUrlAccessForPrincipal returns true, no matter if the current user is in SomeDifferentGroup or not.

I have assured that the configuration is correct. Visiting a page for which the current user is not authorized opens the Windows-Authentication and prompts the user to provide valid credentials.

---

Any ideas why the behavior differs depending on whether authorization-rules are set on a directory or folder level?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so after 2 days of digging I finally found the answer.
Apparently, some ASP.NET projects omit the .aspx file-ending in the URL.

If one now were to call the CheckUrlAccessForPrincipal method with a URL that is missing the .aspx ending, the method will somehow not recognize correctly that the URL is a page and not check the web.config authorization rules correctly.

Manually adding the file-ending to the URL has fixed the problem.