# How to check if a user has access to a specific file in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, webforms, config

I am trying to check if a user has access to a specified location in ASP.NET web forms. The `web.config` file in a subfolder is defined using:

```
<!-- this is located in a subfolder -->
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?"/>
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
  <location path="page.aspx">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <deny roles="SOME_ROLE" />
            <allow users="*" />
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

Trying to open the location when logger when logged in as user in this role correctly redirects me to the login screen, so the config seems to be correct.

However, when I call `UrlAuthorizationModule.CheckUrlAccessForPrincipal` for this page, it always returns `true` (as long as any user is signed in, regardless of role).

How do I check access for a location in a subfolder?

Comment: I closed this a dupe of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54551844/1488067). Turns out that the issue is that I am using a Url rewriter which, among other things, removes the `.aspx` extension. When no user is logged in, `UrlAuthorizationModule.CheckUrlAccessForPrincipal` returns false for these extensionless urls, for all users, it probably just matches the start of the virtual path internaly and terminates quickly. I added `.aspx` to the url passed as parameter to this func and it works.